# Whose google API key am I using in [your favourite location supporting app]?

Tags: google-maps, firefox, google-api, geolocation, electron

## A small intro

So I've been playing with the Google maps geolocation API in a cross-platform electron and web application.

Using the no-longer-that-new `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback)` in my browsers (chrome/chromium/firefox and I assume also the other big ones) works just like it always did. In Electron however, I am prompted to register with the API first.

Surprisingly, Google maps requires you to provide a payment address that will then be used to bill your API calls. (You can read up on that here: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use)

According to these guys https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13143 Electron comes with a baked-in API key that's shared by everyone (unless you set your own)

Naturally, the question arises where my browser gets an API key from? Do all browsers come with the same key too? Who is paying for all these calls from, let's say, Firefox? Clearly that one can't be staying within the free-$200-per-month quota.

Is there perhaps an undocumented meta-API for getting API keys on the fly that the browsers use?

Maybe somebody can shed some light on this. Cheers.

## Addendum:

Digging deeper into the topic, I found out the following:

Browser binaries do indeed come with built-in API keys. Apparently, they're managed on a per-distro basis (e.g. chromium on Arch comes with different ones than Ubuntu, etc.)

You can verify this for example by checking out

`git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/chromium-dev.git`

which will nonchalantly state their keys in `PKGBUILD` (this is **open source**, so I'm not disclosing anything secret here, despite one of the fields being not-so-aptly named *secret*).

```
# Google API keys (see http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys)
# NOTE: These are for Arch Linux use ONLY. For your own distribution, please
# get your own set of keys. Feel free to contact foutrelis@archlinux.org for
# more information.
_google_api_key="AIzaSyDwr302FpOSkGRpLlUpPThNTDPbXcIn_FM"
_google_default_client_id="413772536636.apps.googleusercontent.com"
_google_default_client_secret="0ZChLK6AxeA3Isu96MkwqDR4"
```

A quick search on google reveals a good handful of projects misappropriating Arch's key for themselves already.

In addition to this being an obvious gaping hole in the key management on arch-chromium's side, the issue stretches much further than that.

You might have noticed that the google-maps-app on mobile also works without GPS services enabled (and therefore most likely falls back to the IP-based API). Now assume *somebody* reverse engineers *that key*. What can Google even do? Blanket-banning every single installation of Google-Maps seems suicidal. Forcing a patch to replace the broken key only postpones the issue until it's broken again.

## A verdict?

It seems like there are some ***golden*** API keys floating around the internet. Some belong to big companies, some belong to open source foundations and some others belong just to regular people.

For most intents and purposes these are not really of any great interest to us as developers. If we make mobile applications we get GPS, which is far more accurate anyway. If we make web applications we get to use the golden API key of our user's browser vendor (that may or may never run out of its quota).

We only start to even notice that these mechanisms exist if we make desktop applications that rely on location data (which, on the surface of things, seems silly anyway. Desktop are supposed to stay on desks, not move around).

But every once in a while you may run into this issue, and you'll have to ask yourself the moral (or legal?) question wheter a key stored in a GPL-licensed file if open for grabs.

Comment: `getCurrentLocation` (HTML5 geolocation) doesn't require a key

Comment: At least according to this resource (https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) chrome and chromium can be bundled with API keys at compile time, which I assume they are. 

If they somehow are able to hit the geolocation API without a key, I'd be thrilled to learn how to get my Electron to do that - since it is a browser very much capable of HTML5, after all.

Comment: You are asking about Firefox.

Comment: Stackoverflow would flag the question as too generic if I phrased it as "in browsers". The text itself is worded to apply to browsers in general with only Firefox as an example of the concept

Comment: `getCurrentLocation()` "doesn't require a key" because it already has one. If you open about:config in Firefox's address bar and look for the `geo.provider.network.url` setting, you can see it is set to `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%`. However, I don't know how/where to find the value for `%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%`.